# Validar dos objetos con una función

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos objetos:
`Fecha1` y `fecha2`.

Solo puedo hacer uso de uno para un buscador,
Si existe `fecha1` no existe `fecha2` y viceversa.

Tengo dos funciones `validarfecha1` y `validarfecha2`.
Quiero llamarlas dependiendo de cual objeto es el que se esta usando, pero no logro hacerlo mas que de una forma sencilla pero horrible creo .

```
If(fecha1.year){
 If(!validarfecha1()) {
    Return
 }
}


If(fecha2.year){
 If(!validarfecha2()) {
    Return
 }
}
```

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forna mas limpia de evaluarlas de una manera mas agradable sin tantos if.

Comment: Tampoco me parece tan horrible. De todas formas, si sabes que siempre vas a tener una de las dos puedes ahorrarte el segundo `if`con un `else`en el primer `ìf`

Comment: deberías informarte, si estoy en lo cierto, de una propiedad que ayuda a ejecutar funciones dependiendo del objeto que se utilice, me refiero a "instance of". Espero se de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

dado que estas seguro (por tu defincion del problema) de que si no existe una fecha, existe otra, podrias simplificarlo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
If(fecha1.year){
 return validarfecha1();
}

return validarfecha2();
```

si se cumple la primera condicion, tu funcion devolvera el valor de validarfecha1().
si no se cumple, el codigo sigue, por lo que devuelves el valor que te de validarfecha2().